# PC hung no move mouse cursor in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, bug-reporting, .desktop

Sometimes PC hung no move mouse cursor hold.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reboot
or try to update to latest os cause usually gnome center keeps crashing

Comment: Latest os using ubuntu 64bit

Comment: @BulbulHossen You should provide such information in your question by edititng it and not in comments.